# Dialer.exe in windows 10 | Alarm Call Out | Work with MS Access

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-access, voip

Does anyone ever use and know how to configure dialer.exe in windows 10? I'm looking for an auto dialer that can integrate with MS Access to dial out certain users (at least able to add 3-4 users phone number if one didn't pick up) as an alert phone call. Do I need any hardware device or VoIP phone system(preferably over IP phone system. Let me know if you guys have any documentation on how to do it. Thanks

Comment: You would need a modem connected to a phone line or a SoftPhone VOIP service.

Answer (score 4):

[Dialer.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/958143/when-using-dialer-exe-to-make-voice-phone-calls-you-can-hear-the-recip) does nothing more than dial a number.  It cannot transmit any voice or data.  It does not support command line arguments, so it cannot be used in a script.  Honestly, I am surprised it still exists in Windows 10.  You will need a 3rd party program to do your call list.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions what 3rd party program able to handle alert call out that work with MS Access?

Comment: Sadly no. I haven’t seen anyone use a voice dial out in decades. Email is more efficient and more traceable.

Answer (score 0):

I use this software to dial from the command line or from a script [Dial Engine Pro](https://www.phonedialerpro.com). I have a Windows Powershell script that uses the software to send tones down the line that activate and deactivate caller diversion and turn message bank on and off. After 20 years of broadband I still have a need for a dialup modem in my P.C.

I use a Powershell line similar to this to get the computer to dial

```
& Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dial Engine Pro\dial.exe" -ArgumentList "*21 $NumberToDial #";
```